# curlpp error from LibCurl.obj and libcurl_a.lib

Tags: c++, libcurl, curlpp

When executing the following code I receive LNK2019 errors. I have set the Runtime Library as **Multi-threaded (/MT)**:

```
// LibCurl.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
// errors here solved via C:\Users\homeDir\Documents\Tools\curlpp-0.8.1\include
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include "curl/curl.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl_a.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl_a.lib")
#endif

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        CURLcode res;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.dynamsoft.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    printf("Press any key to continue\n");
    getchar();

    curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

    return 0;
}
```

Error is as follows:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(netrc.obj) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup(void)" (??0Cleanup@curlpp@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\LibCurl.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall curlpp::Cleanup::~Cleanup(void)" (??1Cleanup@curlpp@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\LibCurl.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets referenced in function _Curl_cookie_init    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj)    1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__fopen referenced in function _Curl_cookie_init    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fopen LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(vtls.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fopen LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(mime.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fopen LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(netrc.obj) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__fputs referenced in function _Curl_flush_cookies  LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(telnet.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(rtsp.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(imap.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(http.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(hostip.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(url.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(http_proxy.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___time64   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(tftp.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___time64   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___time64   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(hostip.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___time64   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(http.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___time64   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(dotdot.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(curl_sasl.obj) 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(http.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(rtsp.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(vtls.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(url.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncmp   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(connect.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(telnet.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(curl_sspi.obj) 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(url.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fread LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fread LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(vtls.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fread LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(url.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fread LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fread LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(mime.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__fseek referenced in function _Curl_pin_peer_pubkey    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(vtls.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fseek LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fseek LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(mime.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fseek LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__ftell referenced in function _Curl_pin_peer_pubkey    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(vtls.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__getenv referenced in function _curl_global_sslset LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(vtls.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__getenv    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(getenv.obj)    1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__fwrite referenced in function _Curl_init_userdefined  LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(url.obj)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fwrite    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(sendf.obj) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__read referenced in function _curlx_read   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(warnless.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__read  LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi)   1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__write referenced in function _curlx_write LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(warnless.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__write LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___gmtime64 referenced in function _Curl_gmtime LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__strerror referenced in function _Curl_strerror    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp____sys_nerr referenced in function _Curl_strerror  LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___beginthreadex referenced in function _Curl_thread_create LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(curl_threads.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__close referenced in function _file_done   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(file.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__close LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__open referenced in function _file_connect LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(file.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__open  LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi)   1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___fstat64 referenced in function _file_do  LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(file.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___getpid referenced in function _smb_format_message    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(smb.obj)   1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__access referenced in function _curl_mime_filedata LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(mime.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__access    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(access.obi) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___stat64 referenced in function _curl_mime_filedata    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\libcurl_a.lib(mime.obj)  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___open LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi)   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___access   LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\OLDNAMES.lib(access.obi) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4    LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\LibCurl\MSVCRT.lib(*chandler4gs*.obj)    1
Error   LNK1120 29 unresolved externals LibCurl C:\Users\939508\Documents\C++ Projects\LibCurl\Debug\LibCurl.exe    1

**Please refer to [Visual Studio 2017 and curlpp library LNK2019 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935492/visual-studio-2017-and-curlpp-library-lnk2019-error?noredirect=1#comment80818286_46935492) if you would like to see my configurations for my project.**

Comment: If your debug and release libraries are named the same `libcurl_a.lib` I don't see the point of the #ifdef _DEBUG

Comment: You've screwed up your lib path. Reset it to the default and only use the *additional library path* setting under linker settings.